Duplicate a specific character in a string
My current attempt:
pub async fn sanize_string(input : String) -> String {
     let output = input
        .chars()
        .flat_map(|c| if c == '\'' { iter::repeat(c).take(2); } else { iter::once(c).take(1);  } )
        .collect::<String>();

        return output;
}

Goal: Example with O'Brian as input -> O''Brian as output

Ignoring the typos. Then the main issue is that iter::once() and iter::repeat() is two different types.
In this case, you can easily fix it by simply always using iter::repeat(), i.e.:
    .flat_map(|c| {
        let n = if c == '\'' { 2 } else { 1 };
        iter::repeat(c).take(n)
    })

For more complex cases you can use an enum and impl Iterator for it, and then return the enum. However, instead of manually implementing that you can simply itertools::Either. Which would look like this:
    .flat_map(|c| {
        if c == '\'' {
            Either::Left(iter::repeat(c).take(2))
        } else {
            Either::Right(iter::once(c))
        }
    })

As an aside, your function can accept input: impl AsRef<str> instead of String. Since we don't need to own the String anyways. It also doesn't really have to be async. You also have a typo in sanize_string missing t and i.
Complete Example:
use std::iter;

fn sanitize_string(input: impl AsRef<str>) -> String {
    input
        .as_ref()
        .chars()
        .flat_map(|c| {
            let n = if c == '\'' { 2 } else { 1 };
            iter::repeat(c).take(n)
        })
        .collect::<String>()
}

or
use itertools::Either;
use std::iter;

fn sanitize_string(input: impl AsRef<str>) -> String {
    input
        .as_ref()
        .chars()
        .flat_map(|c| {
            if c == '\'' {
                Either::Left(iter::repeat(c).take(2))
            } else {
                Either::Right(iter::once(c))
            }
        })
        .collect::<String>()
}


Here is another solution with String.replace.
use std::iter;

fn main() {
    let foo = String::from("O'Brian");
    let item_to_replace = "\'";
    let replacement = iter::repeat(item_to_replace).take(2).collect::<String>();

    let result = foo.replace(item_to_replace, replacement.as_str());
    println!("{}", result);
}


replacement is just item_to_replace.repeat(2).
